# WebDriver, ChromeDriver, Selenium, and Jenkins Integration

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium script written in eclipse, which invokes a ChromeDriver that launches a URL, reads title and closes the browser. I'm able to successfully execute this in Eclipse and also at a command prompt.

However, when I create a Jenkins job with a build routine (via execute batch command) the build keeps running for a long time. Upon tracing with sysout statements, I found that the build is stopping at drive.get()

```
driver.get("google.com");
```

The build fails with the error message below after waiting for a long time:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3) on port 39626
Only local connections are allowed.
[304.538][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 298.714
[904.539][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
[914.540][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium Webdriver actually needs display to work (X server to be accurate).

You can use Xvfb to run it in a headless mode, detailed instruction (a bit outdated, but still valid) - http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2012/11/19/installing-selenium-with-jenkins-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for the details. I read thru the documentation and I installed xvnv plugin which is equilvalent for windows. [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvnc+Plugin) But this didnt solve the issue. I still face the same problem.

Comment: Hm... can you double check that DISPLAY variable is defined when you run the build? You can just use "Execute shell" build step in Jenkins and print the variable.

Comment: I re-installed my JDK, jenkins and tried the same with a maven project. The build job ran fine as exected. I didnt configure selenium grid/xvnv.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the code to

```
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

you must have seen error running from eclipse and command prompt.

Comment: I didnt mention http in my question here., but I had that in my source code. you are right, http or https is required for invoking any url from soruce.

Comment: If you had http in your source code I cannot see it. I can only see what you have typed here. What is the point in marking answer down. Bad attitude!!!